# I had applied for UK visa recently and it got refused

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals

[image]

(refused latter UK embasy)

The decision :

i have refused your application
for a visit visa because I am not satisfied that you meet the requirements of paragraph 4.2 of appendix V : immigration rules for visitors because:

- you stated that you wish to visit the UK for 6 days as a tourist.
- under the UK immigration rules you must show that you are qualify for a visa by explaining your own circumstances and the plans you have for visit.it is your responsibility to satisfy me that they are such that if guaranteed leave to enter you will abide by all of the conditions attached to any such leave and that you will leave the United Kingdom on completion of proposed visit.
- You state that you are unemployed. You have stated that you are traveling withe your spouse and that he is funding your visit.you have not stated that how you are supported.you have provided property documents withe your application but this documents do not dimostrareate that you drive an income from them.i also note that when your spouse received his uk visa last October he stated that he had an online business. The documents you have provided do no demonstrate this business or that you or your spouse receive and income such a business. The documents you have provided do not demonstrate how you support your self in bangladesh and as such I am not satisfied that they are an accurate reflection of your financial circumstances in bangladesh
- On the evidence available to me today, I am not satisfied that your circumstances are as stated in your application. Therefore I am not satisfied that you are a genuine visitor to the UK for a purpose that is permitted by the visitors rules or that you intend to leave the uk at the end of your proposed trip (appendix V: 4.2 a c

I am going to reapply. What was wrong with my previous application? What do I need to provide in addition to other documents so as to ensure that I get the visa? What was wrong with my earlier application and what corrective steps should I take for my next application?

thanks in advance 
Farhana Rumpa

Comment: @farhana rumpa UKVI have stated what was wrong with your application - you did not prove your and your husband’s financial circumstances.

Comment: @farhana rumpa UKVI also noted that your husband's prior visa application said he had an online business, but the current application did not mention the online business. The inconsistency between the two applications was also held against you.

Comment: Also, whatever you do, don't lie on the visa application; it'll get you permanently banned from the UK if they catch you.

Comment: nick sir , we dont give any false information and documents all was genuine and true.

Comment: traveller sir, hello traveller sir, yes i had a misstake i dont put withe application my husband business documents by misstake , becoz someone told me your husbands allrady have uk visa and they have all documents your husband allrady in there systems. so i misstake that i don’t attached withe my application file.  amd my husband leaving in italy , there have bussness documents and all documents, should i translate withe english language?

Comment: david sir, yes sir we didn’t attached by misstake , becoz (someone’s told me, as i said up). my husband business documents, license and yearly  income declaration. so david sir, i have to attache all this documents when i apply next? what should i have prepare now? becoz i am planing i will apply agin after 4 month.